# Using an <a> onclick to open an ajax content into a fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, fancybox

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="myLink" onclick="$(this).fancybox({href : 'myPage.php'});">Open ajax content</a>
```

Note that I MUST NOT use a script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myLink").fancybox({href : 'myPage.php'});
   });
</script>
```

I want to trigger a fancybox from an `<a>` onclick element. But into this onclick function, it MUST have the 'href' from fancybox, exactly as I wrote above. But as I wrote, it doesn't work. Please help :)

Comment: `I MUST NOT use a script like this`.... why?

Answer (score 1):

after the document ready, bind the button click event.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

      $("#myLink").click(function() {
          $(this).fancybox({href : 'myPage.php'});
      });

 });
```

then there is no need for javascript code in your element.

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">Open ajax content</a>
```

Check this links for the [jQuery click function](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and more about [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#JavaScript)

Comment: It's a good idea, but it doesn't work. Fancybox answers that "the content could not be loaded". As I said above, I MUST use onclick event into the <a> element, or into any other HTML element. But as I experienced, fancybox doesn't allow me to trigger it except through an <a> element with "href". Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#myLink").click();
```

it should trigger the `onclick` event.